# Wordpress comments children customization to work with bootstrap?

Tags: wordpress, templates, twitter-bootstrap, comments, customization

I have been searching whole day how to customize comments template on Wordpress. Im working on new wordpress theme and trying to build it using bootstrap. At the end comment template got me stuck.

I never liked how wordpress customize comments and it was always pain to customize it, and now twitter bootstrap have nice comment nesting using media list.

But problem is that wordpress use different nesting for children comments.

What i have rendering on template now is this

```
<div id=comments">
   <ul class="media-list">
      <li id="comment-124" class="media">
         <div class="avatar pull-left">
           avatar image
         </div>
         <div class="media-body">
            <div class="media-heading">
               comment info like time when posted
            </div>
            <p> comment text </p>
         </div>
      </li>
      <ul class="children">
         And than children comment template from replies
      </ul>
   </ul>
</div>
```

What twitter bootstrap use is children comments nested inside main comment like this

```
<ul class="media-list">
   <li class="media">
      <a class="pull-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64">
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
         <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
         ...

         <!-- Nested media object -->
         <div class="media">
         ...
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

What i need basically is to change ul="children" to load inside media-body class

While i was searching for solution i came across some explanations that wordpress here uses Walker_Comment class to customize comments template and there is  inside it but when i try to change or do some of my own customization nothing happens.

Does anyone have any explanation how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding the workflow both with wordpress and bootstrap.

`Wordpress` does `NO NESTING` on comments as per se. ( see remark below )

`Bootstrap` is some kind of a styling framework that has `NO NESTING` as per se.

Your `theme` does that , and that changes with every theme, (but you did not specify which theme it is ..)

To edit it , open your comments.php template file and you could style it anyhow you want .

What you look for are functions that are called `Template tags` or in your specific case , `Comments template tags` ( [LINK](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags#Comment_tags) )

in your code , the part where you wrote `avatar image` is actually produced by a function

`get_avatar()` [Codex Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar)

and the `comment date` by (surprise surprise ) :

`comment_date()` [Codex Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_date)

The `comment text` is produced by ( get ready to be surprised again )  :

`comment_text()` [Codex Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_text)

And so on ..

Now , you should consider using a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) if instead of editing the theme directly.

Now , after clearing that , wordpress DOES have some kind of nesting function natively , but as I just explained, it is not a magic-does-all function, but it depends on how your theme is made . These settings can be found under `admin -> settings -> discussion`

there you will find

```
Enable threaded (nested) comments 10 levels deep (nesting)
```

and

```
Break comments into pages with 50 comments per page (pagination)
```

..and also other settings ( depending also on your wp version ) ..

That being said - there are a LOT of bootstrap "empty" or "started" themes that will help you do the work (or at least understanding why your approach was a bit wrong )

For example :

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/the-bootstrap

https://github.com/Facens/wpbootstrap

http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/

http://braginteractive.com/bootstrap/

https://github.com/enile8/Bootstrap-for-WordPress

http://320press.com/wpbs/features/

and I could list some 10 or 20 more , but I think in this case , GIYBF..

Comment: I think you understood me wrong or maybe i didn't explained well. I said i'm working on new theme, and i know how to customize little things you mentioned but main problem was how to change position where children comments (comment replies) are placed, and for that i needed custom walker to override defaults. I finally found solution here https://github.com/retlehs/roots/pull/683 it's using custom walker to change threaded comments.

Comment: you can achieve exactly the same thing without a custom walker and with default functions and some CSS... but hey, if it works for you, then "walker" it is .. :-)